# Can we open GUI based software's via SSH if not then why?

Tags: ssh, ftp, putty

I use the client of remote `Ubuntu 18.04` server via Putty and WinSCP. But still, I need to run software on my personal computer, which is an old computer and can not do the heavy lifting.

How can I run software like **"PyCharm", "Word", "Browser"** on the server?
If this is not possible then why it is not possible.

If I can open a .py file via `WinScp` Editor then why not a .html as webpage.

This may seem a very silly question but I think silly is not asking a question.

Comment: You need an XServer running locally + enable `X11 Forwarding` in Putty for the connection. Then you can EXPORT DISPLAY and run GUI programs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I export DISPLAY from a Linux terminal to a Windows PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/325630/how-can-i-export-display-from-a-linux-terminal-to-a-windows-pc)

Answer (score 1):

> If I can open a .py file via WinScp Editor then why not a .html as webpage.

Well, in the first place, the WinSCP editor isn't opened "via ssh" at all – it is part of WinSCP and runs locally on your computer. (WinSCP downloads the file, lets you edit it, then uploads it back whenever you hit 'Save'.)

And you could certainly do the same to open a .html file in Firefox – but just like the editor was local, Firefox would be running locally and *not* on the server.

*Can* you run graphical programs remotely through SSH? Yes, using "X11 forwarding", although it doesn't provide great performance. You'll need to install an "X server" on your client machine – there are a few options for Windows – then enable X11 forwarding in PuTTY.

However, some apps might be slow (or even unusably slow) – even though X11 was meant to be a network protocol 40 years ago, it only worked well for programs made 40 years ago, but not for highly graphical ones like browsers of today. Something like Xpra or VNC would probably work much better.